# I am running into this error when attempting to create an XLSX in RStudio

Tags: r, excel

> install.packages("xlsx")
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/xlsx_0.6.5.tgz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 370371 bytes (361 KB)
> ==================================================
> downloaded 361 KB

The downloaded binary packages are in
/var/folders/0g/h70b_3hx4hn10c2hybzy_4l40000gp/T//RtmpzUFLGT/downloaded_packages

> library("xlsx")
> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
> Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: JVM could not be found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
running command '/usr/libexec/java_home' had status 1
2: In fun(libname, pkgname) :
Cannot find JVM library 'NA/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'
Install Java and/or check JAVA_HOME (if in doubt, do NOT set it, it will be detected)

> write.xlsx(start_no_data)
> Error in write.xlsx(start_no_data) : could not find function "write.xlsx"

Comment: even after running this code

> install.packages("rJava", dependencies = TRUE)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/rJava_1.0-6.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1140421 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/0g/h70b_3hx4hn10c2hybzy_4l40000gp/T//RtmpzUFLGT/downloaded_packages

Answer (score 0):

uhh so apparently I needed to actually download Java first!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).